# Integration respect the Lévy measure

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory, numerical-methods

How I can compute numerically
$$\int_{a}^{b}f(z)\nu(dz)$$ 
where $\nu$ is a Lévy measure and $f$ is a continuous function?

Is it equivalent to
$$\int_{a}^{b}f(z)d\nu(z)$$

Thanks

Comment: Those are two different notations for the same thing.

Comment: You stumble on *this* and you are studying *Lévy measures*? How comes?